# symfony fetchall with manyToOne relation returning same object multiple times

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony so its likely I am doing something wrong...

This is my DB with relation

[image]

I am trying to create API that will return things back, but student controller will return "grade" table in some nested strange form

```
class StudentController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/student", name="student")
     */
    public function getSubjects()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Student::class);
        $result = $repository->findAll();

        return $this->json($result, Response::HTTP_OK, [], [
                ObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => false,
                ObjectNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['student'],
                ObjectNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object) {
                    return $object->getId();
                }]
        );
    }
```

API will return:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "OIB": 2147483647,
    "name": "Amalia",
    "surname": "Hill",
    "address": "Derick Ports 82330",
    "dateOfBirth": "2008-03-26T00:00:00+01:00",
    "postalCode": {
        "id": 241,
        "name": "SOMEWHERE",
        "postalCode": 31000,
        "__initializer__": null,
        "__cloner__": null,
        "__isInitialized__": true
    },
...
    "scores": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "subject": {
                "id": 3,
                "code": "eng11",
                "name": "ENGLISH",
                "grade": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "grade": "1",
                    "__initializer__": null,
                    "__cloner__": null,
                    "__isInitialized__": true
                },
                "scores": [
                    {},
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "subject": {
                            "__initializer__": null,
                            "__cloner__": null,
                            "__isInitialized__": true
                        },
                        "score": 3,
                        "description": "Excepturi vitae ipsam sunt.",
                        "date": "2020-04-21T00:00:00+02:00"
                    },...
```

as you can see I have scores inside and that's OK, but inside score I have another score and I don't know how to get rid of it, any ideas?

```
// App\Entity\Student.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StudentRepository::class)
 */
class Student
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Score::class, mappedBy="student")
     */
    private $scores;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->scores = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return Collection|Score[]
     */
    public function getScores(): Collection
    {
        return $this->scores;
    }
```

PS, that score with ID = 19 and rest, is all scores with same subject_id

Comment: ObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH should not be true? if you want a depth limit.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth

Comment: @PascalYu I was just trying to figure that field out - but failed, so it was leftover in code

Comment: Do you need the getScores() from subject? Remove it,  can be a quick fix  if you don't need to get scores from subject

Comment: I was trying to put it there so I can get every student grade and later calculate average, or should I write Query inside StudentRepository for that?

Comment: Both works, but i think you should not remove it if you need it .

Comment: regarding that is MAX DEPTH solution here or I need something else?

Comment: I don't think MAX DEPTH is the solution . YOu just want to get rid of the second scores (that is from subject) , right?

Comment: I suggest 2 solutions:
-The fast solution is : to change the function name getScores() from Subject, for sample getAllScores() , and to add in the ignoring attributes : ObjectNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['student','allScores'], 
-The second solution, but it's heavy:  is to add annotations @Groups({"group1") to all property you need, and add ObjectNormalizer::GROUPS =>['group1']

Comment: the first solution is a really quick fix and fixed issue, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function name `getScores()` from Entity Subject, for sample `getAllScores()` , and  add in the ignoring attributes :

```
return $this->json($result, Response::HTTP_OK, [], [
                ObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => false,
                ObjectNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['student,allScores'],
                ObjectNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object) {
                    return $object->getId();
                }]
        );
```

more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes)